# "SQL ORDER BY" where 1 and 2 should be handled equal

Tags: sql, sorting, select, sql-order-by

I have a SELECT query in which I am sorting by several columns

```
SELECT * FROM tablex
WHERE
    date = '$date' AND
    type = '1'
ORDER BY
    column_1 ASC,
    CASE column_2 WHEN '00:00:00' THEN 'b' ELSE 'a' END,
    column_2 ASC,
    column_3 DESC
```

The values in column_1 can be the numbers from 1 to 4 and now I want the values '1' and '2' to be handled equal. So they should be handled as if they're all '1' e.x.

Thx for your help.

Comment: You've already demonstrated you can use `case`. How is what you're trying to do different from what you already have in your query?

Comment: Use another case expression.

Comment: See my comment for the answer, then you know why :)
thx for your time anyway - don't know why you downvote my question though ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first handle the case that they are 1 or 2, use a `CASE`:

```
SELECT * FROM tablex
WHERE
    date = '$date' AND
    type = '1'
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN column_1 IN(1, 2) THEN 0 ELSE column_1 END ASC,
    CASE column_2 WHEN '00:00:00' THEN 'b' ELSE 'a' END,
    column_2 ASC,
    column_3 DESC
```

Comment: Had the exact same query but without the "ASC" the the end - didn't know it's possible to combine it into the CASE expression - so my result was the same as in the query in my question. Now I just removed the "column_1 ASC," and it's just fine :)
Thx a bunch!

edit: yes, that's what I was talking about - works like this!